# MySQL causes high disk read

Tags: mysql

As the title mentioned, MySQL cause a highly usage of disk ,especially read operation.

the info about disk usage:
[image]

and the disk usage process of mysqld (iotop -p $MYSQLD_PID)
[image]

I don't know how cause this.

Comment: A disk read of `0.00 B/s` does not look pretty high to me

Comment: @NicoHaase sorry for my bad description, I have added some info there, The picture was showing the disk usage only for  mysqld